# Number formatting using regex with special characters

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs

I am learning regex and I want to implement this in react app so when I write something on input field I want to allow user to write only numbers and maximum one space. This string also must starts with **+** character. My regex tool shows me good result but in app I cannot write anything.

```
const handlePhone = ({currentTarget}) => {
    let val = currentTarget.value;
    // Regular expression
    const reg = /^\+\d+/g;
    const isNumber = val.match(reg);
    if (isNumber || val === '') {
      setFieldValue('phone', val);
    }
  };
```

With this expression I wanted to implement this: starts with + and later you can write some digits.

[image]

But in app I cannot write anything. Why this tool is so different from this live matching?

With this:

```
const reg = /^\+\d+( \d+)*$/;
```

[image]

Comment: Because your regex requires `+` and 1 digit to be already present. Change to `const reg = /^\+\d*(?:\s\d*)?$/;`. Also, it will only work for live validation. You will probably need another regex for on-submit validation, like `const reg = /^\+\d+(?:\s\d+)?$/;`. Also, it makes sense to use `RegExp#test(String)` to check if a string matches a regex.

Comment: so you are calling this with keypress, up, down, funkychickendance?

Comment: I am calling this with onChange method from Formik library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need something really simple like `/^\+\d* ?\d*$/` which means:

- `^\+`  starts with '+'
- `\d*`  then zero or more digits
- `?`  (space?) then zero or one space
- `\d*`  then zero or more digits
- `$`  end of string

E.g.

```js
function checkValue(el) {
  let re = /^\+\d* ?\d*$/;
  document.getElementById('err').textContent = re.test(el.value)? 'good':'bad';
}
```

```html
<input oninput="checkValue(this)"><br>
<span id="err"></span>
```

Comment: Yep. The OP didn't say it had to have numbers, just that it could only have numbers and maximum 1 space.

Comment: Wow that's great, can you please update this to optionally starts with + or number but when you write number '+' is no more allowed ??

Comment: I *could*, but … the regexp would then start with `^[+\d]`.

Comment: Have you some good source where can I teach more regex technics ?

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
^\+?\d+( \d+)?$
```

- `^` - start anchor
- `\+?` - optionally start with a plus sign
- `\d+` - require at least one digit to follow
- `( \d+)?` - Optionally allow a space which must be followed by one or more digits
- `$` - end anchor

https://regex101.com/r/pxbefb/1

Comment: With this my isNumber const return me 'null' and I cannot write anything

Comment: Added screenshot for you

Comment: It will also accept 2 spaces . i.e., +123 123 132 . which OP don't want .

Comment: @Freestyle09 I am not familiar enough with react to suggest code improvements.

Comment: When you match whole string It works but on live not :/ anyway thanks

Comment: @Freestyle09 Sorry I can't help more but I am not familiar with react. I updated my regex to make the leading `+` sign optional per your comment on one of the other answers

Answer (score 0):

Try out this regex , And also check the regex in this **[LINK](https://regex101.com/r/to9Vp3/2)**

```
const reg = /^\+\d+ \d+$/gm;
```

> ^+ :- will check that string is starting with +. 
>   \d+ :- this will allow 1 or more digits 
>   \s :- This will allow only one space . 
>   $ :- this will ensure that string ends with digit and this will restrict the second use of space character .

Comment: `\s` allows any whitespace character, not just space.

Answer (score 0):

My Regex is pretty bloated but it should work.

```
const regex = \^\+[\d]+(\s)*(\d)+$\g;
```

1. ^+ just negates the power of +
2. [\d]+ is letting you pick 0-9 digits 1 or more times
3. (\s)* is a group and it allows for 0 or 1 space
4. (\d)+$ can pick digits between 0-9 one or more time. And $ is just the end anchor